# Security concerns with protobuf Any fields?

Tags: java, security, polymorphism, protocol-buffers

SO!

I'm considering using an `Any` field in a service-to-service (over the wire) request object:

```
message ServiceRequest {
   google.protobuf.Any envelope;
}
```

Clients would send arbitrary data packed in the `envelope` field, and the server would dispatch to request handlers based on the unpacked type information (achieving a kind of polymorphic dispatch). Requests with unrecognized types would be logged/dropped. Clients and servers will likely be built using Java.

My central question is: Are there security risks (or other significant) drawbacks to this approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't *entirely* arbitrary - it needs to actually be recognized as a local protobuf type *or* treated as an opaque payload. It doesn't allow the caller to instantiate arbitrary types locally, which is a security hole in a few systems (`BinaryFormatter` in .NET, for example). So: I wouldn't be hugely alarmed by it, by I wonder if a `oneof` would be more appropriate, as that constrains things to things you *actively expect*.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned oneof - it's the alternate approach I'm considering. It would certainly improve type safety. Here's the issue I'm wrestling with: Multiple client services will use these requests for varied purposes, and there will almost certainly be different (though related) services responding to the requests. The oneof field risks becoming a kitchen sink, and acts as a coupling point between unrelated requests. Not to mention the increase in cross-component dependencies.

Comment: @PeterLittig `Any` is *also* the same kitchen sink - just: you're covering your eyes and pretending that it isn't there; it sounds like what you *really* want here is to partition the services more granularly